# maven pom file has html code instead of xml

Tags: xml, maven, pom.xml

I am running mvn install from the command line, and I get the following error...

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one   of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model
[ERROR] [FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\Gary\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-resources-plugin\2.6\maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom: entity reference names can not start with character '&' (position: START_TAG seen ...nction d(a){var c,d,e,f=b.createElement("canvas"),g=f.getContext&&... @14:89)  @ line 14, column 89
```

I decided to open the pom file for maven-resources-plugin:2.6 in my local maven repository, and this is what I discovered:

**maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de-DE">
<head>
<title>Mein Block &#8211; Ein weiterer WordPress-Blog</title>
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="template" content="Ignite 1.60" />
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.5.3" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Mein Block &raquo; 
...
```

It's a german wordpress-blog file for some reason.

My settings.xml is the default file in both the .m2 directory and the conf directory.  I have also updated to the most recent version of Maven.

One more thing, I have noticed that may be helpful is a file in the same directory as the poms called _remote.repositories, which has the following content:

```
#NOTE: This is an Aether internal implementation file, its format can be    changed without prior notice.
#Thu Jul 14 10:22:00 EDT 2016
maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom>release-repo1.php-maven.org=
maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom>central=
```

Can you please help me figure out why my project will not build correctly?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have this when I have company repositories in project and I'm not on VPN. To fetch all libs I do this:

1._I add Mvn dependency to pom.xml at the begining (You can omit this step if You don't have ):

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mvn</id>
        <name>mvn</name>
        <url>http://maven.icm.edu.pl/artifactory/repo/</url>
    </repository>
...other resps
```

2._I remove whole .m2/repositories dir or I search for broken files with :

```
grep -R -l -L groupId  --include \*.pom   //Search all that not contain groupId string
```

(execute this in .m2 dir)

Answer (score 1):

I have looked up the pom of maven-resources-plugin 2.6 in Maven central, and it is just a usual pom, not the strange HTML file you have. So you probably should delete (parts of) your local repository and reload the files from Maven Central.