# Maven pom file has html code instead of xml springboot starter parent pom file

Tags: xml, maven, pom.xml

Similar to this question... [maven pom file has html code instead of xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377371/maven-pom-file-has-html-code-instead-of-xml)

Error while doing maven build

> ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
>
> org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were
> encountered while processing the POMs:
>
> [FATAL] Non-parseable POM
> C:\home\jenkins\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\1.5.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.6.RELEASE.pom:
> unexpected markup <!d (position: START_DOCUMENT seen <!d... @1:3)  @
> C:\home\jenkins\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\1.5.6.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-1.5.6.RELEASE.pom,
> line 1, column 3

Attached the pom file that is generated when I do a maven clean and install. Why is it printing something gibberish in html instead of xml.

[Content of pom file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4XEe.jpg)

Comment: This looks like a network error ... firewall/proxy issue..turn on checksum policy to prevent such things https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/

Comment: Note that `mvn clean` does not cleanup your local repository. You need to cleanup corrupted artifact manually.

Comment: I would recommend to delete your whole `$HOME/.m2/repository`... and rebuild your project... furthermore upgrade your project because spring boot version 1.X is long EoL ...